# Forming circuit with straight moves

Tags: induction, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, invariance, chessboard

I am reading about a problem where we have a rectangular board, and we have to show that it is impossible to complete a circuit of the board if both sides have odd length.
Circuit is a sequence if moves of $1$ square vertically or horizontally, which visits all the squares exactly once and ends to the starting square.
My question is about the solution provided which goes as follows:

> The number of moves made must equal the number of squares. After an
> odd number of moves, the color of the current square is different from
> the color of the starting square. So for odd number of moves we can't
> form a circuit as we can't return to the starting square.

So the solution uses the approach of coloring the chessboard, and although I understand it, it seems to me something is missing. I.e.
How does the explanation cover the case that after an odd number of moves we could end up adjacent to the starting square and hence form a circuit? In theory it seems to me that it could happen i.e. hasn't been dis proven. Or is that already covered in a subtle way I am not understanding?

Comment: @Peter: We could still be adjacent to the starting square in the end and form the circuit no?

Comment: After the last move , we must be on the original square, otherwise we have not completed the circuit. And the number of moves is fixed since every square must be visited exactly once. Hence the number of moves must be equal to the number of squares.

Comment: @Peter: yes, but if the number of moves is one more than the number of squares how does the case of being in an adjacent to the starting square and hence it is possible to move to the staring square covered?

Comment: Or is it that every square except the original one is visited exactly once, the original exactly twice and that's why the number of moves is exactly the number of squares?

Comment: @PeterMelech To visit all the other squares exactly once, we must make a number of moves one less than the number of squares. The final move is the return to the original square. With "visit" , it is meant that a move leads to that square, hence the beginning does not count as a first visit. Or alternatively, if it counts as a visit, the number of moves is one less than the number of visits. The result is the same.

Comment: @Jim we can of course eventually return to the original square, but the parity argument proves that we cannot satisfy the requirement then that every square (apart from the original one, if we count the start configuration as a first visit) must be visited exactly once. We have no freedom in the number of moves, this is the crucial part.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, that's exactly what I tried to say, but much better formulated.

Comment: @Peter: If we end up in an adjacent square to the starting square visiting everything else once we can just hop to the adjacent staring square and finish the loop. How does the parity imply what I described is impossible? This is the part that I am confused

Comment: Visiting everything else means visiting an even number of new squares (because together with the starting square we have an odd number of squares in total). That means an even number of moves where every move visits a new square. After an even number of moves we end on the same colour as we started with. So the last new square visited is the same colour as the starting square. This cannot be adjacent to the starting square.

Comment: Example: on a $5\times9$ board, a circuit takes $45$ moves. Hence getting next to the starting node takes $44$ moves, and you would have two neighboring squares of the same color.

Comment: The property holds for any shape with an odd number of squares.